# Make related posts display first in search result

Tags: categories, search

I'm looking for a solution that makes wordpress website's search result even better.

`Question`: By default, the search result will return all the **not really** related posts at first, as long as the post contained related words that meet the keyword which inserted in the search box while doing searches. **For example**: in the blog i have only 3 posts with different post titles and categorized in different categories. The `1st post title` is **"Exercise Makes Healthy Life"**, `2nd post title` is **"We Train to Be healthy"(which contains "exercise" in the post's paragraph only)** and the `3rd post title` is **"Exercise Everyday is Good For Health"**.

`1st post` and `2nd post` are same category as categorized in **exercise**. And then, the `3rd post` is categorized in **Health**. Then, i entered **exercise** to search, the 1st and 3rd post will be displaying at first **(because there is an "exercise" contained in the post title)** and 2nd post will be displaying as last. I have a category named **exercise** as well.

Therefore, when people searched for a keyword that meets the category i have in the site, all the related posts in the category will display first. And then, display the rest of others posts.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the plugin [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/), it massively enhances the default WordPress search, including searching for categories.

Comment: Hi @TheDeadMedic , sorry that i forgot to mention in the question. I'm looking for the solution without a plugin. Would be preferable with a code that implemented into the file of `functions.php`. Possible?

Comment: Why no plugin? It's easy enough to redirect to category archive if a search match is found, but changing the order of found posts based on category matches is no easy task, a bit outside the scope of WPSE.